# How to test whether image is fully loaded in testcafe

Tags: image, loading, testcafe

I need to create a helper to verify whether the image is fully loaded in testcafe, I'm very new to testcafe.Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the [complete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete) and [naturalWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) properties of the  element. You can access them with the [ClientFunction](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402832/guides/basic-guides/client-functions#header) or [Selector custom DOM properties](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402759/reference/test-api/selector/addcustomdomproperties#header). For example:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`Check images`
    .page`google.com`;

test('Test', async t => {
    const image = Selector('img[alt=Google]').addCustomDOMProperties({
        complete:     node => node.complete,
        naturalWidth: node => node.naturalWidth
    });

    await t
        .expect(image.complete).ok()
        .expect(image.naturalWidth).eql(272);
});
```