# addCustomDOMProperties results in "does not exist on type"

Tags: testcafe

testcafe 2.6.2

I'm having trouble using `Selector.addCustomDOMProperties` to wait for an `<img>` to finish loading before attempting a `t.click()` on it.

When trying to click an `<a>` on my page which contains an `<img loading="lazy">`, the test fails with an error indicating the click couldn't happen because the element has zero size.  I believe the act of clicking causes the page to scroll to the element and immediately click it, but the `img` has not loaded yet because of its lazy loading.

It looks like I should use the `complete` property described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete and referenced in a TestCafe `addCustomDOMProperties` call at [How to test whether image is fully loaded in testcafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457785/how-to-test-whether-image-is-fully-loaded-in-testcafe)

However when I try the following simple attempt to read `nodeName` from an element:

```
    // see https://testcafe.io/documentation/403655/guides/advanced-guides/advanced-selector-techniques
    this.productIndexSelector = this.productIndexSelector.addCustomDOMProperties({
        nodeName: el => el.nodeName
    });
    let name = await this.productIndexSelector.nodeName;
```

The test fails to compile with:

```
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error:

Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
/home/neek/workspace/premierrange158/htdocs/scripts/test/premier.ts (1397, 52): Property 'nodeName' does not exist on type 'Selector'.
```

I see this discussed in 2017 at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1510 but the Issue was closed with a cryptic remark that "It's by design. Take a look at Selector TS tests. You need to declare Selector interface extension."

I've cloned git@github.com:DevExpress/testcafe.git and in `tests` I see test-suites/typescript-defs/selectors.ts but the tests only seem to force an error and don't show the function being used correctly.

How is `addCustomDOMProperties` supposed to work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of how to use addCustomDOMProperties with TypeScript in our documentation: [addCustomDOMProperties](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402759/reference/test-api/selector/addcustomdomproperties).
You need to define your own interface that contains the properties you wish to add:

```js
interface CustomSelector extends Selector {
    innerHTML: Promise<any>;
}

const label = <CustomSelector>Selector('label').addCustomDOMProperties({
    innerHTML: el => el.innerHTML
});

await t.expect(label.innerHTML).contains('input type="checkbox" name="remote"');
```

Comment: Thank you @artem-b, not sure how I missed that! This works. I note that trying to `scrollIntoView()` the A containing my lazy loading IMG also fails saying "The action target ([my_a_selector]) is too small to be visible: 0px x 0px" - I have made it scroll a nearby H2 into view instead, which is enough to get the IMG into view and begin loading, then the `expect(customSelector.complete).ok()` seems to work fine.